# Adding 'and' at the end of a comma separated list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Currently, I'm using the **stuff** function to create a comma separated list per each row.

`x,y,z`

What I want is to add commas for n-1 items in the list, with the final item being preceded by 'and'

`x,y, and z`.

For these purposes, just checking row number won't work because this list is being generated per unique Id, therefore I can't just iterate to the end of the table. Code below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (sw.OwnerID)
            ,stuff((
                SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + e.pn
                FROM fct.enrtablev e
                    WHERE sw.OwnerID = e.OwnerId
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Pet(s)]
```

Comment: What options have you consider? Tried? Got stuck on? (BTW you shouldn't be using `nolock` willy nilly all over the place).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit of a hack... AND `string_agg()` would be a better fit if 2017+

Here we use test the `row_number()` of the item count `sum(1) over()`, when equal this is the last item in the list

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (OwnerID int,pn varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'X')
,(1,'Y')
,(1,'Z')
,(1,'Z')
,(2,'Apples')

Select Distinct
      OwnerID
     ,stuff( ( Select case when row_number() over(order by pn) = nullif(sum(1) over() ,1)
                           then ', and ' 
                           else ', ' 
                       end + pn  
                FROM (Select distinct pn 
                       From @YourTable
                        Where OwnerID = A.OwnerId
                     ) e 
                Order By PN
                For XML Path('')), 1, 2, '')  AS [Pet(s)]
 From @YourTable A
```

**Returns**

```
OwnerID Pet(s)
1       X, Y, and Z
2       Apples
```

Comment: I would probably use `case when lead(pn) over (order by pn) is null` seems a bit simpler to me

Comment: @Charlieface Now that you mention it... it does.   This was just my first thought and got rather zoomed in.

Answer (score 1):

XQUery and XML data model is based on ordered sequences. Exactly what we need.

Here is a simple solution based on XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (OwnerID int, pn VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO @tbl (OwnerID, pn) VALUES
(1,'X'),
(1,'Y'),
(1,'Z'),
(2,'Apples');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT p.OwnerID 
    , (SELECT * 
    FROM @tbl AS c
    WHERE c.OwnerID = p.OwnerID
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
    ).query('
    for $x in /root/r/pn/text()
    return if ($x is (/root/r[last()]/pn/text())[1]) then 
            if (count(/root/r) gt 1) then concat("and ", $x) else string($x)
         else concat($x, ",")
   ').value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS p
GROUP BY p.OwnerID;
```

**Output**

```
+---------+----------------+
| OwnerID |     Result     |
+---------+----------------+
|       1 | X, Y, and Z    |
|       2 | Apples         |
+---------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using ORDER BY and count.

```sql
Declare @YourTable table (OwnerID int,pn varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
 (1,'X')
,(1,'Y')
,(1,'Z')
,(2,'Apples')

;WITH CTE_OwnerIdRank as
(
SELECT ownerid, pn, row_number() over (order by ownerId) as totalrn,
count(*) over(partition by ownerid order by ownerid) as ownercnt
from @yourtable
)
SELECT distinct OwnerId,
            stuff((
                SELECT  ', ' + CASE WHEN c.totalrn = c.ownercnt then CONCAT(' and ',c.pn) else c.pn end
                FROM CTE_OwnerIdRank as c
                    WHERE c.OwnerID = o.OwnerId
                    order by c.totalrn
                    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS [Pet(s)]
from @yourtable as o
```

| OwnerId | Pet(s) |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | X, Y, and Z |
| 2 | Apples |